# Is there a way to authenticate a user against a Local Active Directory on my company's internal app made in Angular

Tags: angular, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I'm developing an internal app for my company. I don't have a back-end, I'm just serving the Angular app's static files from an IIS server.

My company has an Active Directory that works inside the domain.

My Angular app should be able to ask the users for their login/password and verify in the AD if it's correct and the groups that the user belongs.

Is it possible? Is there an angular package to help with that? Or should I use okta/auth0?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft graph api to authenticate, if company has AD in Microsoft

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular

Comment: But MS Graph is for Azure AD, right? My AD is on premises. I don't believe Graph can query local AD.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an internal app (used by employees within organisation network), you can easily enable Windows Authentication for IIS apps (https://mid.as/active-directory-integration/configuring-iis)

Active Directory can also respond to LDAP queries when ADLDS is enabled. Easiest way to query AD would be using LDAP queries : https://www.rebeladmin.com/2018/02/step-step-guide-setup-active-directory-lightweight-directory-services-ad-lds/

Having said that, you're better integrating Active Directory with an identity provider like Okta or Azure AD to make your integration future proof.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at it. From what I got so far, I'll really have to create an intermediate Identity Server or install something like Okta to handle it from the Angular side (since it's not served by .net).